# Compute difference between specific element in two lists that are in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that contains multiple lists -

```
[[568, 436, 176, 84, 405],
 [1890, 436, 177, 82, 404],
 [2069, 436, 102, 82, 403],
 [2173, 436, 202, 81, 402],
 [5, 437, 71, 83, 401],
 [78, 437, 182, 83, 400],
 [263, 437, 139, 83, 399],
 [404, 437, 162, 83, 398],
 [747, 437, 170, 82, 397],
 [920, 437, 169, 82, 396],
 [1091, 437, 171, 82, 395],
 [1265, 437, 168, 82, 394],
 [1436, 437, 127, 82, 393],
 [1565, 437, 138, 82, 392],
 [1705, 437, 183, 81, 391],
 [263, 520, 139, 84, 390],
 [2069, 520, 102, 82, 389],
 [2174, 520, 202, 81, 388],
 [1566, 521, 137, 82, 387],
 [1706, 521, 182, 81, 386],
 [1891, 521, 176, 81, 385],
 [3, 522, 73, 82, 384],
 [78, 522, 183, 82, 383],
 [405, 522, 161, 82, 382],
 [569, 522, 176, 82, 381],
 [747, 522, 170, 82, 380],
 [920, 522, 169, 82, 379],
 [1092, 522, 170, 82, 378],
 [1265, 522, 169, 81, 377],
 [1436, 522, 127, 81, 376],
 [2069, 604, 102, 82, 375],
 [2174, 604, 202, 82, 374],
 [1566, 605, 137, 82, 373],
 [1706, 605, 182, 82, 372],
 [1891, 605, 176, 81, 371],
 [747, 606, 171, 82, 370],
 [920, 606, 169, 82, 369],
 [1092, 606, 171, 82, 368],
 [1265, 606, 169, 82, 367],
 [1436, 606, 127, 81, 366],
 [5, 607, 71, 82, 365],
 [78, 607, 183, 82, 364],
 [263, 607, 139, 82, 363],
 [405, 607, 161, 82, 362],
 [569, 607, 176, 82, 361]]
```

I need to compute the difference between the second element of each list, and if the difference is greater than 80, separate the list into individual list of lists, with an added index to separate them

Expected Output -

List 1 -

```
 [568, 436, 176, 84, 405],
 [1890, 436, 177, 82, 404],
 [2069, 436, 102, 82, 403],
 [2173, 436, 202, 81, 402],
 [5, 437, 71, 83, 401],
 [78, 437, 182, 83, 400],
 [263, 437, 139, 83, 399],
 [404, 437, 162, 83, 398],
 [747, 437, 170, 82, 397],
 [920, 437, 169, 82, 396],
 [1091, 437, 171, 82, 395],
 [1265, 437, 168, 82, 394],
 [1436, 437, 127, 82, 393],
 [1565, 437, 138, 82, 392],
 [1705, 437, 183, 81, 391]
```

List 2 -

```
 [263, 520, 139, 84, 390],
 [2069, 520, 102, 82, 389],
 [2174, 520, 202, 81, 388],
 [1566, 521, 137, 82, 387],
 [1706, 521, 182, 81, 386],
 [1891, 521, 176, 81, 385],
 [3, 522, 73, 82, 384],
 [78, 522, 183, 82, 383],
 [405, 522, 161, 82, 382],
 [569, 522, 176, 82, 381],
 [747, 522, 170, 82, 380],
 [920, 522, 169, 82, 379],
 [1092, 522, 170, 82, 378],
 [1265, 522, 169, 81, 377],
 [1436, 522, 127, 81, 376]
```

List 3 -

```
 [2069, 604, 102, 82, 375],
 [2174, 604, 202, 82, 374],
 [1566, 605, 137, 82, 373],
 [1706, 605, 182, 82, 372],
 [1891, 605, 176, 81, 371],
 [747, 606, 171, 82, 370],
 [920, 606, 169, 82, 369],
 [1092, 606, 171, 82, 368],
 [1265, 606, 169, 82, 367],
 [1436, 606, 127, 81, 366],
 [5, 607, 71, 82, 365],
 [78, 607, 183, 82, 364],
 [263, 607, 139, 82, 363],
 [405, 607, 161, 82, 362],
 [569, 607, 176, 82, 361]
```

This needs to repeatable for any number of lists present and not just three

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far?

Comment: We see a lot of question like these on SO. But if you ask a question you should be prepared to answer [what have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). Regardless if you are asking a peer or asking online you should first explain/show what you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: can you use numpy? if yes then you could do: `x,y = np.unique(np.r_[True,np.diff(np.array(a)[:,1])>80].cumsum(),return_counts=True);np.split(a,y.cumsum())`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are ordered already by the second element you can do something like this.

Input:

```
l = [[568, 436, 176, 84, 405], [1890, 436, 177, 82, 404], [2069, 436, 102, 82, 403], [2173, 436, 202, 81, 402], [5, 437, 71, 83, 401], [78, 437, 182, 83, 400], [263, 437, 139, 83, 399], [404, 437, 162, 83, 398], [747, 437, 170, 82, 397], [920,437, 169, 82, 396], [1091, 437, 171, 82, 395], [1265, 437, 168, 82, 394], [1436, 437, 127, 82, 393], [1565, 437, 138, 82, 392], [1705, 437, 183, 81, 391], [263, 520, 139, 84, 390], [2069, 520, 102, 82, 389], [2174, 520, 202, 81, 388], [1566, 521, 137, 82, 387], [1706, 521, 182, 81, 386], [1891, 521, 176, 81, 385], [3,522, 73, 82, 384], [78, 522, 183, 82, 383], [405, 522, 161, 82, 382], [569, 522, 176, 82, 381], [747, 522, 170, 82, 380], [920, 522, 169, 82, 379], [1092, 522,170, 82, 378], [1265, 522, 169, 81, 377], [1436, 522, 127, 81, 376], [2069, 604, 102, 82, 375], [2174, 604, 202, 82, 374], [1566, 605, 137, 82, 373], [1706, 605, 182, 82, 372], [1891, 605, 176, 81, 371], [747, 606, 171, 82, 370], [920, 606, 169, 82, 369], [1092, 606, 171, 82, 368], [1265, 606, 169, 82, 367], [1436, 606, 127, 81, 366], [5, 607, 71, 82, 365], [78, 607, 183, 82, 364], [263, 607, 139, 82, 363], [405, 607, 161, 82, 362], [569, 607, 176, 82, 361]]
```

Code:

```
list_iter = iter(l)
chunks, chunk = [], []
entry = next(list_iter) # Grab the first element
chunk.append(entry) # add it to the first chunk

for x in list_iter:
    if not x[1] < chunk[0][1] + 80:
        chunks.append(chunk)
        chunk = []
    chunk.append(x)
if chunk:
    chunks.append(chunk)

for c in chunks:
    for lst in c:
        print(lst)
    print()
```

Output:

```
[568, 436, 176, 84, 405]
[1890, 436, 177, 82, 404]
[2069, 436, 102, 82, 403]
[2173, 436, 202, 81, 402]
[5, 437, 71, 83, 401]
[78, 437, 182, 83, 400]
[263, 437, 139, 83, 399]
[404, 437, 162, 83, 398]
[747, 437, 170, 82, 397]
[920, 437, 169, 82, 396]
[1091, 437, 171, 82, 395]
[1265, 437, 168, 82, 394]
[1436, 437, 127, 82, 393]
[1565, 437, 138, 82, 392]
[1705, 437, 183, 81, 391]

[263, 520, 139, 84, 390]
[2069, 520, 102, 82, 389]
[2174, 520, 202, 81, 388]
[1566, 521, 137, 82, 387]
[1706, 521, 182, 81, 386]
[1891, 521, 176, 81, 385]
[3, 522, 73, 82, 384]
[78, 522, 183, 82, 383]
[405, 522, 161, 82, 382]
[569, 522, 176, 82, 381]
[747, 522, 170, 82, 380]
[920, 522, 169, 82, 379]
[1092, 522, 170, 82, 378]
[1265, 522, 169, 81, 377]
[1436, 522, 127, 81, 376]

[2069, 604, 102, 82, 375]
[2174, 604, 202, 82, 374]
[1566, 605, 137, 82, 373]
[1706, 605, 182, 82, 372]
[1891, 605, 176, 81, 371]
[747, 606, 171, 82, 370]
[920, 606, 169, 82, 369]
[1092, 606, 171, 82, 368]
[1265, 606, 169, 82, 367]
[1436, 606, 127, 81, 366]
[5, 607, 71, 82, 365]
[78, 607, 183, 82, 364]
[263, 607, 139, 82, 363]
[405, 607, 161, 82, 362]
[569, 607, 176, 82, 361]
```

Though the numpy solution is probably a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data above is called `a` then you could append using the condition:

```
d = {1:[a[0]]}
count = 1
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i+1][1] - a[i][1] > 80: count += 1
    d[count] = d.get(count,[]) + [a[i]]


{1: [[568, 436, 176, 84, 405],
  [568, 436, 176, 84, 405],
  [1890, 436, 177, 82, 404],
  [2069, 436, 102, 82, 403],
  [2173, 436, 202, 81, 402],
  [5, 437, 71, 83, 401],
  [78, 437, 182, 83, 400],
  [263, 437, 139, 83, 399],
  [404, 437, 162, 83, 398],
  [747, 437, 170, 82, 397],
  [920, 437, 169, 82, 396],
  [1091, 437, 171, 82, 395],
  [1265, 437, 168, 82, 394],
  [1436, 437, 127, 82, 393],
  [1565, 437, 138, 82, 392]],
 2: [[1705, 437, 183, 81, 391],
  [263, 520, 139, 84, 390],
  [2069, 520, 102, 82, 389],
  [2174, 520, 202, 81, 388],
  [1566, 521, 137, 82, 387],
  [1706, 521, 182, 81, 386],
  [1891, 521, 176, 81, 385],
  [3, 522, 73, 82, 384],
  [78, 522, 183, 82, 383],
  [405, 522, 161, 82, 382],
  [569, 522, 176, 82, 381],
  [747, 522, 170, 82, 380],
  [920, 522, 169, 82, 379],
  [1092, 522, 170, 82, 378],
  [1265, 522, 169, 81, 377]],
 3: [[1436, 522, 127, 81, 376],
  [2069, 604, 102, 82, 375],
  [2174, 604, 202, 82, 374],
  [1566, 605, 137, 82, 373],
  [1706, 605, 182, 82, 372],
  [1891, 605, 176, 81, 371],
  [747, 606, 171, 82, 370],
  [920, 606, 169, 82, 369],
  [1092, 606, 171, 82, 368],
  [1265, 606, 169, 82, 367],
  [1436, 606, 127, 81, 366],
  [5, 607, 71, 82, 365],
  [78, 607, 183, 82, 364],
  [263, 607, 139, 82, 363],
  [405, 607, 161, 82, 362]]}
```